# Failed to create parent directories for tracking file .lastUpdated

Tags: java, maven

I've added  `com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.3` to my POM and it
s unable to complete because of the following u

> [INFO] --- dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.3:build (default) @ server-api
>   --- Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-modules-base/2.9.4/jackson-modules-base-2.9.4.pom
>   [WARNING] Failed to create parent directories for tracking file
>   /home/alex/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-modules-base/2.9.4/jackson-modules-base-2.9.4.pom.lastUpdated

Which, in turn, causes:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.3:build (default) on project
>   server-api: Execution default of goal
>   com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.3:build failed: Plugin
>   com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.3 or one of its dependencies
>   could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at
>   com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:jar:1.4.3 ->
>   com.spotify:docker-client:jar:shaded:8.11.4 ->
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.9.4 ->
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.9.4:
>   Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.9.4:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-modules-base:pom:2.9.4 from/to
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   /home/alex/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-modules-base/2.9.4/jackson-modules-base-2.9.4.pom.part.lock
>   (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It had happened for us because some part of `/.m2/repository` was not having correct permissions.

Comment: on ubuntu 18.04 this doesn't help. i have to delete the complete .m2 folder (see another answer). and that works. (see answer of @aclokay)

Answer (score 4):

I removed `~/.m2/` and it worked

Comment: Changing permissions as suggested in other answers might leave a vulnerable/unsecure configuration (chmodin 777 is usually a terrible idea and no app should require it). I removed only `.m2/repository` and recreated it, chowned to the right user using it and the maven goal worked again. +1

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing permissions of .m2 folder and repository. No luck.

Finally updated maven from 3.6.0 to 3.6.3 (latest) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Changing  the file permissions using the following command:

```
sudo chmod 777 repository
```

solves the problem